# How to regex something after first whitespace(s)

Tags: regex

I have a string link `TEST123   DATA`, so this are two words seperated by whitespace. How can I regex the right part after whitespace(s) to get `DATA`? I am new to this and I hoped someone could tell me how to do this? Any characters at the beginning should be skipped including the first whitespace. I need everything after the first whitespace(s). So This are string examples:

```
TEST_1 DATA
TEST     DATA
123  DATA
```

and the result should be always "DATA".
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^\S*\s+(\S+)
```

matches the string from the beginning until the word after the first whitespace(s). Group 1 will then contain the string `DATA` (in your example).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match `DATA`, and you have access to a Perl-compatible regex engine, you can use

```
^\S*\s+\K\S+
```

The `\K` token tells the regex engine to ignore all the text that has been matched so far.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cK5bX3).

With a .NET regex engine, you can use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=^\S*\s+)\S+
```

See it [live on regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=c6ef5d4f-4071-4f8a-96b9-f79679f8744a).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the end of the string, matching everything that isn't a whitespace character:

`[^\s]*$`

Gets all 3 `DATA` in the sample with global and multiline flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following regex: (Python)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "TEST_1 DATA"
>>> result = re.sub(r".*?(\w+)\s*$", r"\1", s)
>>> result
'DATA'
```